# Profile under C:\Users\ "websitename" after IIS website when opened from localhost\websitename

Tags: iis, windows-10

I have a website under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename. If I open it (any browser), Windows creates a user called "websitename" under C:\Users, C:\Users\websitename.

That becomes the actual ACTIVE profile, breaking, well, basically everything.

The user is created in the registry as well here:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-82-1552494301-1869227342-3327666674-1719597003-3231809566`

with a path added:  C:\Users\websitename

I have never encountered this before.

Anyone seen this and have a resolution?  IIS 10 on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is because you did not specify an existing application pool (such as DefaultAppPool) when adding the site. At this time, when you add a site, it will automatically add a new application pool by default（with the same name as your sitename）, and it contains the property **LoadUserProfile=true**.

So this is the main reason why this problem occurs in this case.

[image]
[image]

If you want to avoid this phenomenon, you can create an application pool first, and set its property `LoadUserProfile=false` before adding the site, or use an existing application pool.

And you can find the corresponding description in the official documentation: [Application Pool Identities - User profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#user-profile)